# How simplify this particular sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Can we simplify the following sum?

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}  {(-1)^{i+1}\over 1-2^{-i}}$$

Thank you.

Comment: are you sure that there is such a formula?

Answer (score 0):

By expanding $\frac{1}{1-2^{-i}}$ as a geometric series we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}S=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{1-2^{-i}}&=&\sum_{m\geq 0}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i}(-1)^{i+1}2^{-mi}\\[0.3cm]&=&\sum_{m\geq 0}\left[1-(1-2^{-m})^n\right]\\[0.1cm]&=&\sum_{m\geq 0}2^{-m}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(1-2^{-m})^j.\tag{1}\end{eqnarray*}$$

I think that we cannot further simplify this sum, but the last representation gives an easy way to bound $S$.